# Efficiency of encrypting multiple parts of a document with Rijndael

Tags: c#, performance, security, encryption

I have a large xml document which contains a large amount sensitive data.  I have an algorithm  which encrypts this data with Rijndael.

```
byte[] encrypted;
using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
{
  rijAlg.Key = EncyptionManager.RijndaelKey;
  rijAlg.IV = EncyptionManager.RijndaelIV;
  rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

  ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);
  using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
  {
    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
     {
        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
        {
          swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
        }
        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
     }
  }
}
return encrypted;
```

Assuming the vast majority of the file needs to be stored encrypted is it more efficient to create an xml document and encrypt the entire contents of the file, or to leave the xml schema intact and only encrypt the specific fields?

Comment: You're asking if encrypting one block is more or less efficient than encrypting multiple blocks?

Comment: @PeterRitchie, yes - assuming the total of the smaller blocks is less than the length single one.  In other words is it size or number of encryptions which is the biggest drain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is of course much more secure to encrypt the entire file (the whole XML bytestream). If you encode only specific nodes of the XML document then anybody who cares to look will still be able to plainly see the whole structure of the document, including how many of which types of elements are present.

The only reason you should consider doing anything else is if you have a requirement that the structure of the document needs to be visible and manipulable by your code without decrypting, i.e. the code that manipulates the object does not have access to the encryption key.

Encrypting the entire document will also be much more efficient in terms of key management, file handling logic. Plus, under many encryption modes that use an IV or padding up to a block size, it will be much more space-efficient to encrypt the entire file.

Still, your security requirement, not performance, should be your main concern.

Answer (score 2):

No static answer possible. The optimal point depends on the exact count and sizes of the blocks because the algorithm has a fixed set-up cost. Encrypting two blocks is less than twice as expensive than encrypting one block.

The only valid answer is to benchmark to find the cut-off point.